# Is calling a Controller From Another Controller a good practice in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-5.1

I was able to implement a `PaypalController`, with a reusable `postPayment()` method, which accepts items and their prices, and creates a Paypal payment, and redirects to a Paypal payment page.

```
class PaypalController extends Controller {

    private static $_api_context;

    private static function initialize() {
        //initialize api context
    }

    public static function postPayment($items, $currency, $description) {
        self::initialize();

        //create item list, transaction, payment objects, etc

        $payment->create(PaypalController::$_api_context);
        ...
        return redirect()->away($redirect_url); // redirect to paypal
    }
}
```

`PaypalController` is called statically by other controllers. For example, the  `AuthController` might call it to request payment from the user right after the user registers to my site:

```
class AuthController extends Controller {
    public function postRegister(Request $request) {
        return PaypalController::postPayment($items, 'JPY', 'description');
    }
}
```

Basically, `PaypalController` returns a `Redirect` to `AuthController`, which also returns it, to perform the redirect to the Paypal payment page.

I was wondering if this is a good design - a controller calling a different controller, is it?

If not, what would be a better way to do this? Maybe move my code from PaypalController into custom Service Provider, or custom Helper, or something else? I am very new to Laravel, and I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not a good practice. You should abstract the business logic to a service/repository class. So for example:

Create an interface as Contract:

```
namespace App\Services\Paypal;

interface PaypalInterface {

     public function PostRegister(Array $array, /*More $params if necessary*/); 
}
```

Then implement the Contract:

```
namespace App\Services\Paypal;

class PaypalService implements PaypalInterface {

    // Must match the method signature declared in the interface
    public function PostRegister(Array $array, /*$More $params if necessary*/) {

        // Do the process here
    }
}
```

Then use the contract/interface as dependency. So, in your `PaypalController` or in any other Controller you may (re)use it like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Request;
use App\Services\Paypal\PaypalInterface;

class AuthController extends Controller {
    public function postPayment(Request $request, PaypalInterface $paypalService) {
        return $paypalService->postRegister($request->all());
    }
}
```

In this case, [register the binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding) (interface to implementation) in a service provider (Basically in `AppServiceProvider`). That's the basic workflow. Why an interface because, Controllers (Client/Consumer classes) should talk to Contract/Interface instead of a concrete implementation.

[This article of mine may help you](http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern) but remember this is not the 100% decoupled, it's still coupled with `Laravel` framework and you can even more decouple the Service.

---

*Note: It's a best practice but don't blindly follow this approach for every projects/problems, just chose wisely when you should do it, it really depends on the context but don't just die for it. The current context is fine to follow this.*

Comment: Why would I want to use an interface? I am afraid that I might over-engineer if I use an interface in this particular case.

Comment: That's the right/best practice to decouple the business logic, that's to say that: Program to an interface, not to concrete implementation. In otherwords, The dependency on abstract type (interface) keeps the both parties from being tightly decoupled and lets to chnage the dependenct even without toching the application logic. But like I said, do what you think is better for yourself, don't follow any rule until you realise the need and until you understand it. It's brought topic, anyways.

Comment: Also, [Check This](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=program%20to%20an%20interface%20not%20an%20implementation).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your `postPayment` is a static method is a code smell for me that tells "Nope, not inside a controller".

- As you said, I think a service would be a better place for that, you can take a look at [Omnipay](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal) if you want to.
- You can make `PaypalController` abstract too and `AuthController` would extend this one (only if you have to use `postPayment` inside multiple Controllers).
- You can do a `PaypalTrait` and use it inside your `AuthController` (only if you have to use `postPayment` inside multiple Controllers).
- Of course you can combine the first solution with the others if it makes sense to you.

There are many answers for this question and I don't think that the perfect one exists, it really depends on what you're building and what you need.

Comment: Others have suggested using a Service Provider, but I like the Trait idea for its simplicity. I am new to both concepts, but would a trait be appropriate in my case? If I understand correctly, a trait would be for implementing multiple inheritance, and it doesn't feel right to have Paypal processing be "inherited". What do you think?

Comment: Yep you could do a `CanProcessPayment` Trait and use it in every Controller that need a method that handles PayPal. But don't make it static and rename your `initialize` method to be sure there is no collision in the naming... If you look at the BaseController of Laravel, it uses multiple Traits to had functionality to every Controllers. The abstract PaypalController is not a bad solution too, works like the Trait, you just have to inherit your Controllers with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way to do it. Rember, controllers should only take a request and dispatch it to the right service, not handle buisness logic by themselves.

This rule apply: when you need to call a controller method from another controller it smells of bad code

Instead, use a service provider and a service class to handle your paypal logic. The service class will handle the paypal logic and will be used later when you'll need it in the controllers:

```
//SERVICE CLASS
class PayPalService
{
    public function processPayment(){ //... }
}
```

The service provider is used to register the service class in the application: your're telling Laravel that when you'll need a `PayPalService` it should build and return it for you

```
//SERVICE PROVIDER: binds the creation of the service in the ioc container
class PayPalServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        //use singleton or bind to bind the service in the ioc container
        $this->app->singleton( PayPalService::class, function()
        {
            return new PayPalService();
        });
    }
}
```

Then, when you need the `PayPalService` class you should let Laravel inject the service automatically in your controllers:

```
class AuthController extends Controller 
{   
    public function postRegister(Request $request, PayPalService $paypal) {
        return $paypal->processPayment();
    }
}
```

If you want, You could further improve this design by using an interface for the service class

Comment: In your last example, did you mean: `return $paypal->processPayment();` ?