# Laravel - How to add private routes for internal programitic use only?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm using Semantic Versioning for my API with url paths to each version all going to the same generic endpoint. ie. I'm not prefixing /v1 or /v2 to the url's it's just one /url/path/to/endpoint

I have middleware processing the version header the generic controller calls the appropriate Controller.Major version to handle processing. The controllers are called using this method detailed by jeffochoa.
https://jeffochoa.me/redirect-a-request-to-a-specific-route-laravel

The end Controllers are private and the routes to them should also be private and only called programatically - ie. not accessible to the outside world.

Is there a way to add private routes to Laravel that are for **internal**  use only?

For example, can I make the **macro.test** route below available for internal use?

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'API'],function() {
    Route::get('/test',"testAPIController@get");
    Route::get('macro.test', ['as' => 'macro.test', 'uses' => 'macrotestAPIController@get']);
});
```

Comment: Please add some more detail as this is a more generic question more appropriate for another exchange.

Comment: @fth What other exchange? And what other detail do you suggest the question needs? I thought the question was pretty simple to understand?

Comment: @fth Have just it more complicated than it needed to be. Hopefully that satisfies you?

Comment: @fth ? What other exchange would generic questions be more appropriate in? I would appreciate if you could add some more detail to your criticism.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a middleware that will check if the route is accessed from inside or outside and respond accordingly.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class EnsureAccessIsInternal {

    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->getCallerIp() !== 'your-ip')
        {
            abort(403); //it's from outside, forbidden status
        }

        return $next($request); //continue
    }

    private function getCallerIp()
    {
      //here add the logic 
    }
}
```

And then in your routes

```
Route::group(function () {
    Route::get('/my-secret-route', [
      'as' => 'macro.test', 
      'uses' => 'macrotestAPIController@get'
    ])->middleware(EnsureAccessIsInternal::class); 
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. Do you know if the “as” / “uses” part can be dropped and just retrieve the route into using the /my-secret-route part part? The /my-secret... part is sort of redundant at the moment because I was retrieving it by the “as” name.

Comment: You mean like this: Route::get('/my-secret-route', [macrotestAPIController::class, 'get']);?
Anyway, if you are new with Laravel, just follow the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: Sort of - but using a 'name' in place of the URI. The docs don't specify anything about having  name based ONLY routes (with no URI) so I thought someone on here might have come up with a solution.

Comment: Oh, just use the helper route('macro.test') to get the URI later.

If that is not what you are searching for, than please, provide an example from other framework for everyone to see and understand what you need.

Comment: I just tried this solution and checking the IP address doesn't really work because in this scenario someone with an external IP address IS actually calling the first Controller, which is then calling the next Controller internally. But the IP address that's getting passed through is that of the original external user.

Answer (score 0):

Read your article. Although you can call a controller's function from another, it's a bad practice. See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645919/is-calling-a-controller-from-another-controller-a-good-practice-in-laravel).

Tag routes (movie routes):

```
/movies/accion
/movies/comedy
/movies/kids
/movies/lord-of-the-rings-2
```

Should be `/movies/{selector}` and the request will be handled by your `TagController`.

Article routes:

```
/movies/10-action-movies-for-the-weekend-123
/movies/2020-upcoming-movies-124
/movies/top-100-classic-movies-125
```

Should be `/articles/{selector}` and the request will be handled by `ArticleController`. Why? Because articles are not movies.

Comment: Hmmm.... this is for "versioning" of the routes. It could probably be done in middleware. So the API receives the same request to /my/endpoint and then the Version header get parsed and then the appropriate controller is called ie. Controller0, Controller1, Controller2 etc. Instead of using different urls /v1 /v2 /v3 etc.